# MySQL, get averages for all days of the week

Tags: mysql, aggregate, average

I have a table that contains data stored for every hour a spot in my location is unavailable or free. My current query gets the average occupancy / free spots of an entire day:

```
SELECT AVG(sz.occupied), AVG(sz.free)
FROM `hourly_cache` AS sz
WHERE   sz.time BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-02 00:00:00'
        AND HOUR(sz.time) BETWEEN 8 AND 22
        AND libID = 0
```

But what if I want the average for not just this day, but every other day of the week? Say: I want the average for Monday of this week, plus Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.

How do I loop through each day and on each day run this query based on what day it is?

I was thinking of doing it in PHP but was wondering if there's an approach that works in MySQL?

Comment: Why not add a “day” column to the query and get the results for all days in 1 query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be too many solutions depending on business logic and how You want render it.

1) Distribute `time` field to `date` and `time` and then group by `date`:

```
SELECT AVG(sz.occupied), AVG(sz.free), date, time
FROM `hourly_cache` AS sz
WHERE   
  (sz.date >= '2017-01-01' AND sz.date < '2017-01-07')
  AND HOUR(sz.time) BETWEEN 8 AND 22
  AND libID = 0
GROUP BY date;
```

2) Convert time to date and group by date:

```
SELECT AVG(sz.occupied), AVG(sz.free), DATE(sz.time) as date
FROM `hourly_cache` AS sz
WHERE   
  (sz.time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND sz.time < '2017-01-07 00:00:00')
  AND HOUR(sz.time) BETWEEN 8 AND 22
  AND libID = 0
GROUP BY date;
```

3) Use `DAYOFWEEK` function

```
SELECT AVG(sz.occupied), AVG(sz.free), DAYOFWEEK(sz.time) as day_of_week
FROM `hourly_cache` AS sz
WHERE   
  (sz.time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND sz.time < '2017-01-07 00:00:00')
  AND HOUR(sz.time) BETWEEN 8 AND 22
  AND libID = 0
GROUP BY day_of_week;
```

4) Add `day_of_week` and `week_num` fields to `hourly_cache` table, set them on insert or update.

then query it like:

```
SELECT AVG(sz.occupied), AVG(sz.free), week_num, day_of_week
FROM `hourly_cache` AS sz
WHERE   
  (sz.time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND sz.time < '2017-01-07 00:00:00')
  AND HOUR(sz.time) BETWEEN 8 AND 22
  AND libID = 0
GROUP BY week_num, day_of_week;
```

5) If You cannot change table structure You can create a view (but I'm not sure about performance):

```
CREATE VIEW v_avarage_seats_by_date AS 
  SELECT 
    AVG(sz.occupied) as occupied, 
    AVG(sz.free) as free, 
    DATE(sz.time) as date,
    DAYOFWEEK(sz.time) as day_of_week
  FROM `hourly_cache` AS sz
  WHERE   
    (HOUR(sz.time) BETWEEN 8 AND 22) AND libID = 0
  GROUP BY date;
```

then query it like:

```
SELECT * FROM v_avarage_seats_by_date WHERE date >= '2017-01-01' AND date =< '2017-01-07'
```

Comment: @AranBins happy that was helpfull